# почему может не удалятся файл

Tags: java

я объявляю файл, и удаляю его `file.delite();` , он не удаляется, я по новому объявляю, вот код

```
    if(content.contains("1223994251")) {
                    String phn="C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\XobDanii.txt";
                    File file2= new File(phn);
                    file2.delete();
                       if (file2.delete()) System.out.println("File deleted!");
                       Thread.sleep(3500);
                       file2.createNewFile();
                       Files.write(Paths.get(phn), content.getBytes());
```

Comment: Вы вызываете `file2.delete()` два раза и вывод в консоль делаете на втором. `"File deleted!"` вы не увидите никогда - потому что если файл не может быть удалён, то и второй вызов его не удалит, а если первый вызов его удалил, то второй вернёт `false`, так как не может удалить файл, которого уже нет. Если вы хотите убедиться что файла нет то проверьте `if (!file2.exists()) System.out.println("File deleted!");`

Comment: `java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\Альфа\XobDanii.txt: Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом.`

Comment: Это значит что на момент попытки удаления где-то есть не закрытый поток на запись или чтение этого файла. Может быть как в вашем коде, так и в другой программе, использующей этот файл.

Comment: спасибо, я забыл оказывается закрыть поток filereader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через java.nio лучше:

```
    boolean isDeleteFile = false; // Не удалять файл (можно включить)

    try {

        final String path_to_file = "" +
                "C:\\Users\\" +
                System.getProperty("user.name") +
                "\\XobDanii.txt";

        Path phn = Paths.get(path_to_file);

        try {

            // Избыточно - файл уже удален - не было исключения.

            if (Files.exists(phn) && isDeleteFile) {

                Files.delete(phn);

                System.out.println("Файл удален!");

            } else {

                System.out.println("Нечего удалять - нет файла.");

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new IOException("Ошибка удаления файла: " +'\n' + e);
        }


        try {

            if (!Files.exists(phn)) {

                Files.createFile(phn);

            }

            System.out.println("Файл создан: " + phn);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new IOException("Ошибка создания файла: " + "\n" + e);

        }

        try {

            OpenOption file_options = StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING;

            //OpenOption file_options = StandardOpenOption.APPEND;

            Files.write(phn, new String("Test stirng.").getBytes(), file_options);

            System.out.println("Записан файл - его новая длинна: " + Files.size(phn));

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new IOException("Ошибка записи файла: " + "\n" + e);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Ошибка работы с файловой системой: " + "\n" + e);
    }

} //END: test_file_system()
```

Comment: мне написало
, файл удален,так какого хрена, в него записались данные еще раз, ведь при удалении, должны были быть новые данные, а там старый и новый

Comment: Отредактировал пример. Теперь удаление файла в первой части отключено (оставил в качестве примера). Для записи в файл задал опцию TRUNCATE_EXISTING, которая заставляет удалять из файла все старые данные перед записью.